# Why does my `require` statement cause a LoadError?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, irb

I've installed the `money` gem:

```
$ gem install money
Successfully installed money-6.0.1  
1 gem installed  
Installing ri documentation for money-6.0.1...  
Installing RDoc documentation for money-6.0.1...
```

After installing, I started an IRB session and tried to load it using `require "money"`, but I got a `LoadError`:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- money  
    from (irb):1:in `require'
    from (irb):1
```

Why did this cause a `LoadError` even after I successfully installed the gem?

Comment: What is `it` in `what it the cause`? What is `ird`? What is `should of`?

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with your load paths. You need to add information to your question about how you've installed Ruby (rvm, rbenv, system?).

In the meantime, this may let you get started working with the gem, at least:

```
require(`gem which money`.strip)
```

Comment: I installed ruby using RVM.

Comment: Typed `require(`gem which money`.strip) got

LoadError: no such file to load -- i18n
 from /Users/cyrusghazanfar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/money-6.0.1/lib/money.rb:3:in `require'
 from /Users/cyrusghazanfar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/money-6.0.1/lib/money.rb:3
 from (irb):1:in `require'
 from (irb):1
1.9.3-p484 :002 >

Comment: thanks, its still not working. How can i fix my load paths. Sorry i'm new to programming.